# How to keep tkinter button on same row as label and entry box

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I am creating a simple entry UI to intake 2 text fields and a folder path. I'm just getting started with tkinter and I can't get the browse button to appear next to the entry field for the CSV file. Instead it appears with the other buttons.

I have read the tkinter tutorial. I've tried three different Frame ideas from coworkers and the web. I did try to put this in an element, but either my brain is fried or I'm just not good enough to understand how that works. I think grids might be my answer, but as this is the first UI I've tried like this I can't follow the code.

```
import tkinter as tk
fields = 'Version', 'Database Name', 'CSV File'

def fetch(entries):
    for entry in entries:
        field = entry[0]
        text  = entry[1].get()
        print('%s: "%s"' % (field, text))

def callback():
    path = tk.filedialog.askopenfilename()
    entry.delete(0, tk.END)
    entry.insert(0, path)

def initUI(root, fields):
    entries = []
    for field in fields:
        if field == 'CSV File':
            frame = tk.Frame(root)
            frame.pack(fill=tk.X)

            lbl = tk.Label(frame, text=field, width=20, anchor='w')
            lbl.pack(side=tk.LEFT, padx=5, pady=5)           

            entry = tk.Entry(frame)
            entry.pack(fill=tk.X, padx=5)

            btn = tk.Button(root, text="Browse", command=callback)
            btn.pack(side=tk.RIGHT,padx=5, pady=5)

            entries.append((field, entry))
        else:
            frame = tk.Frame(root)
            frame.pack(fill=tk.X)

            lbl = tk.Label(frame, text=field, width=20, anchor='w')
            lbl.pack(side=tk.LEFT, padx=5, pady=5)           

            entry = tk.Entry(frame)
            entry.pack(fill=tk.X, padx=5, expand=True)

            entries.append((field, entry))
    return entries

if __name__ == '__main__':
    root = tk.Tk()
    root.title("Helper")
    entries = initUI(root,fields)
    root.bind('<Return>', (lambda event, e=entries: fetch(e))) 
    frame = tk.Frame(root, relief=tk.RAISED, borderwidth=1)
    frame.pack(fill=tk.BOTH, expand=True)

    closeButton = tk.Button(root, text="Close", command=root.quit)
    closeButton.pack(side=tk.RIGHT, padx=5, pady=5)
    okButton = tk.Button(root, text="OK", command=(lambda e=entries: fetch(e)))
    okButton.pack(side=tk.RIGHT)
    root.mainloop()
```

I am wanting the Browse button next to the entry field instead of its current location down with the OK and Close buttons.

Side problem... I can't figure out how to get my callback to work!

Comment: Are you aware that `pack` has several options, and that if you don't explicitly tell it what to do, it will stack widgets from top to bottom?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> **Question**: How to keep tkinter button on same row as label and entry box

To reach this you have to `pack` the `Entry` and `Button` into a own `Frame`.

> **Note**: Use always `side=tk.LEFT` to get the widgets in a row.

This example shows a `OOP` solution: 
[image]

- Define a `class LabelEntry` inherited from `tk.Frame`.

  ```
  class LabelEntry(tk.Frame):
      def __init__(self, parent, text, button=None):
          super().__init__(parent)
          self.pack(fill=tk.X)

          lbl = tk.Label(self, text=text, width=14, anchor='w')
          lbl.pack(side=tk.LEFT, padx=5, pady=5)
  ```
- Condition: If a `Button` passed, create a new `Frame` to `pack` the `Entry` and `Button`.

  ```
          if button:
              frame2 = tk.Frame(self)
              frame2.pack(side=tk.LEFT, expand=True)

              entry = tk.Entry(frame2)
              entry.pack(side=tk.LEFT, fill=tk.X, padx=5)

              button.pack(in_=frame2, side=tk.LEFT, padx=5, pady=5)
          else:
              entry = tk.Entry(self)
              entry.pack(side=tk.LEFT, fill=tk.X, padx=5)
  ```

> **Usage**:

- Define a `class App` inherit from `tk.Tk`.

  ```
  class App(tk.Tk):
      def __init__(self):
          super().__init__()

          self.title("Helper")

          frame = tk.Frame(self)
          frame.grid(row=0, column=0)
  ```
- Loop the `fields` and create a `LabelEntry` object

  ```
          entries = []
          for field in 'Version', 'Database Name', 'CSV File':
              if field == 'CSV File':
                  button = tk.Button(text="Browse", command=self.callback)
                  entries.append(LabelEntry(frame, field, button))
              else:
                  entries.append(LabelEntry(frame, field))
  ```
- Run the Application.

  ```
  if __name__ == "__main__":
      App().mainloop()
  ```

***Tested with Python: 3.5***

Comment: using Python 3.6.8, getting below error when running your solution:
`AttributeError: '_tkinter.tkapp' object has no attribute 'callback'`
This is about code line:
`button = tk.Button(text="Browse", command=self.callback)`