# How to make dynamic widget creation in tkinter python?

Tags: python, tkinter

For example, to the input we get an indefinite number of values ​​(value1, value2, value3, ...) - a maximum of 20.

For each value I need to create a Label and Entry widget.

For example:

```
widg_label = Label (root, text = value1, width = 7, height = 2, bg = bc, fg = 'white', font = 'Arial 12')

widg_entry = Entry (root, width = 7, font = 'Arial 12')
```

As you understand, each widget must have a unique variable name in order to get data from Entry.

I repeat, there can be an undetermined number of such widgets (up to 20).
How can this be implemented? 
Thanks.

Comment: Use a list of widgets. You could have two lists (one for `Label`s, one for `Entry`s), or you could have one list of tuples, one `Label` and `Entry` per tuple.

Comment: _"As you understand, each widget must have a unique variable name in order to get data from Entry."_ - that's not exactly true. You must store a reference, but it doesn't have to be via a unique variable name.

Comment: Follow this approach: [create a LabelEntry object](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54591761/7414759)