# Tkinter lack of responsiveness

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter, responsive-design

I'm trying to create a simple GUI using Python's Tkinter module. So far I've created this, but as you can see from the images below when I try to resize the window with dragging it loses its form.

Why it is like that and can it be changed?

This is normal.

[image]

And this is when I drag the form. It doesn't look good.

[image]

This is the code:

```
self.fontTemp = tkfont.Font(
            family='Calibri', size=12, weight="bold")

    LabelFrame1 = tk.LabelFrame(
        self, text="INFO 1", font=self.fontTemp, padx=10, pady=10)

    LabelFrame1.pack(padx=10, pady=10)
    LabelFrame1.place(relx=0.5, rely=0.2, anchor=tk.N)

    left = tk.Label(LabelFrame1)
    left.pack(padx=160, pady=25)

    self.ime = tk.Entry(self, width=30)
    self.ime.place(relx=0.4, rely=0.3, anchor=tk.W)
    self.ime.insert(0, "")

    self.prezime = tk.Entry(self, width=30)
    self.prezime.place(relx=0.4, rely=0.38, anchor=tk.W)
    self.prezime.insert(0, "")


    name1Label = tk.Label(self, text="NAME: ")
    name1Label.place(relx=0.4, rely=0.3, anchor=tk.E)
    name2Label = tk.Label(self, text="NAME: ")
    name2Label.place(relx=0.4, rely=0.38, anchor=tk.E)
```

Comment: I advise you to avoid using `place`except for very specific cases because you need to manually adjust everything, It is way easier to `grid` your labels and entries in the LabelFrame instead and there are plenty of questions on SO and tutorials about resizing the GUI elements with grid.

Comment: Read up on [When to use the Place Manager](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/place.htm). Follow this approach [how-to-keep-tkinter-button-on-same-row-as-label-and-entry-box](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54584673/how-to-keep-tkinter-button-on-same-row-as-label-and-entry-box/54591761)