# Tkinter packing entrys at different column than button

Tags: python, tkinter, tkinter-entry, pack

I am using a simple code:

```
frame_bottom = Frame(root)
frame_bottom.pack(fill='x')

button1 = Button(frame_bottom, text = 'One', command =  visualize)
button2 = Button(frame_bottom, text = 'Two', state = DISABLED)
label_rango1 = Label(frame_bottom, text = 'Sigma value:')
e_sigma = Entry(root, borderwidth = 2)

label_rango1.pack(side='left',  expand=True)
e_sigma.pack(side='left')
button1.pack(side='left',  expand=True)
button2.pack(side='left', expand=True)
```

Howerer, despite of using `side='left'`, the entry is placed below the rest of the buttons. Any idea on how to pack everything in the same line?

Thanks!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to keep tkinter button on same row as label and entry box](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54584673/how-to-keep-tkinter-button-on-same-row-as-label-and-entry-box)

Comment: It is because `e_sigma` is child of `root` and the others are children of `frame_bottom`.

Answer (score 1):

The reason is due to the fact that `button1` and `button2` are children of `frame_bottom`, but `e_sigma` is a child of `root`. You pack `frame_bottom` before `e_sigma` and don't provide any options, so `frame_bottom` is being added to the *top* of the root window (well, top of the available space, which matters if you've already packed other widgets in the root window). When you pack `e_sigma` it must go in the remaining space which by definition is below `frame_bottom`.

Put another way, `frame_bottom` and `e_sigma` are both children of `root`. `frame_bottom` is packed first and `e_sigma` is packed second, both with default options. Therefore, `frame_bottom` will appear above `e_sigma`.

If you want the entry to be to the right of the buttons, it needs to have the same parent as the buttons.