# Iterate through YAML in Python

Tags: python, tkinter, yaml

I'm trying to build a Python application that has a Tkinter GUI.
I got stuck there that I don’t understand how to literate through the read yaml string by keys. I want the values of `field_names` to be the names of the `Entries` in the code and the values of `labels` are the properties of `labels text`.

> **cfg.yml** looks like this:

```
- field_name: neptun_code
  label: Neptun code
- field_name: result
  label: Result [%]
- field_name: mark
  label: Mark [1-5]
```

> **config.py** looks like this:

```
from pathlib import Path


class Config(object):

    def __init__(self):
        self.document_yaml = None

    def function(self):
        self.from_yaml()

    def from_yaml(self):
        self.document_yaml = Path("./cfg.yaml").read_text()
        return self.document_yaml
```

> **Main.py** The problem here is that I don’t know how to use the yaml list and how to iterate through it in `def labels(self)` and `def entries(self)`

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import messagebox


class Window(object):

    def __init__(self):
        self.name = None
        self.window = None
        self.lbl = None
        self.txt = None


    def show(self):
        self.create_window()
        self.labels()
        self.entries()
        self.window.mainloop()

    def create_window(self):
        self.window = tk.Tk()
        self.window.title("MainWindow")
        self.window.geometry('350x200')

    def labels(self):
        # label
        row = 0
        for key, value in yaml_str: #?????
            self.lbl = tk.Label(self.window, text=value)
            self.lbl.grid(column=0, row=row)
            row += 1

    def entries(self):
        # entry
        row = 0
        for key, value in yaml_str: # ??????
            self.txt = tk.Entry(self.window, textvariable=self.name, width=20)
            self.txt.grid(column=1, row=row)
            row += 1



my_window = Window()
my_window.show()
```

Comment: You want something like this: [label and entry box](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54591761/7414759)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Install the pyyaml library:

```sh
pip install pyyaml
```

Now convert your yaml to a python list and process it:

```py
import yaml

from pathlib import Path
document_yaml = Path("./cfg.yaml").read_text()

yaml_list = yaml.load(document_yaml)

print(yaml_list)

# [{'field_name': 'neptun_code', 'label': 'Neptun code'}, {'field_name': 'result', #'label': 'Result [%]'}, {'field_name': 'mark', 'label': 'Mark [1-5]'}]

# So labels, for instance, will be:

    def labels(self):
        # label
        row = 0
        for item in yaml_list:
            self.lbl = tk.Label(self.window, text=item["label"])
            self.lbl.grid(column=0, row=row)
            row += 1
```

Full Example:

```py
import yaml
from pathlib import Path

class Config(object):

    def __init__(self):
        self.document_yaml = Path("./cfg.yaml").read_text()

    def load_yaml(self) -> list:
        return yaml.load(self.document_yaml)


class Window(object):

    def __init__(self):
        self.name = None
        self.window = None
        self.lbl = None
        self.txt = None
        self.config = Config().load_yaml()

    def show(self):
        self.create_window()
        self.labels()
        self.window.mainloop()

    def create_window(self):
        self.window = tk.Tk()
        self.window.title("MainWindow")
        self.window.geometry('350x200')

    def labels(self):
        # label
        row = 0
        for item in self.config:
            self.lbl = tk.Label(self.window, text=item["label"])
            self.lbl.grid(column=0, row=row)
            row += 1
```

Comment: Thank you! Now i can reach the values by keys. One more question, how can i initialize "class Config(object)" in Class Window () to get the list? I tried and when i tried to use print() the output was None.

Comment: I'm not familiar with TkInter and how you instantiate the config. But I included a full example above where I forced the config in the Window class. hopefully, it gives you some clues?