# How to align Buttons in a new window, tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter, tkinter-button

The buttons don't align on the same row. The second one moves upward instead. All the examples online use grid, which doesn't apply since I am using pack. I don't know how to use grid. What do I do?
Example:

[image: Example]

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk

#Create an instance of tkinter window
root = Tk()
root.geometry("600x450")

#Define a function to close the window
def close_root():
        root.destroy()

#Define a function
def open_new():
        #Create a TopLevel window
        new_win= Toplevel(root)
        new_win.title("My New Window")

        #Set the geometry
        new_win.geometry("600x250")
        new_win.attributes('-fullscreen', True)
        Label(new_win, text="Hello There!",font=('Georgia 15 bold')).pack(pady=30)

#Create a Button in main Window

Label(root, text="Game",font=('Georgia 15 bold')).pack(pady=30)
btn= Button(root, text="New Window",command=open_new)
btn.pack(side=BOTTOM, anchor='w', padx=5, pady=5)

btn1= Button(root, text="New Window",command=open_new)
btn1.pack(side=BOTTOM, anchor='e', padx=5, pady=5)

root.attributes('-fullscreen', True)
```

Comment: Why are you setting the window size with `geometry` and then later setting `-fullscreen`? Also you should read up on the `pack()` method and `grid()` method to get a full understanding of how they work.  Grid sounds like the most appropriate for how you are looking to implement your widget layout.  Read [this info](https://tkdocs.com/tutorial/grid.html)

Answer (score 0):

To align widgets in your window by using `pack` you should follow [this approach](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54591761/13541354), i.e. create a Frame for each new row and then `pack`ing widgets via `side=tk.LEFT`.

Personally, I prefer using grid, since you can achieve a much higher degree of personalization with ease. The only requirements is a good logic to split your widgets on your window.

Generally, you'd like to draw vertical and horizontal straigth lines between your widgets, that'll define your rows and columns. For instance, if your widgets `wX` are to be drawn like that:

```
[    w1    ]
[w2]    ⌈w3⌉
[w4]    ⌊  ⌋
```

You could separate them by with lines like (more than one solution exists):

```
    w1
----------
w2 |   |
-------| w3
w4 |   |
```

Thus you know that:

- w1 takes the 1st row, and columns from 1 to 3
- w2 takes 2nd row, 1st column
- w3 takes 2nd to 3rd rows, in 3rd column
- w4 takes 3rd row, 1st column

and you can `grid` them accordingly, using `row`, `column`, `rowspan`, and `columnspan` (see documentation for more details and other useful parameters).

---

In your example, you'd want your title in 1st row, spanning on any column, some big space in 2nd row, and your buttons in 3rd rows, respectively in 1st and last column. For these few elements, we just need 3 rows and 3 columns. Here you go

```
# Title: row 0, 3 columns starting from 0
Label(root, text="Game", font='Georgia 15 bold').grid(row=0, column=0, columnspan=3, pady=30)

# Left button: row 2, column 0
btn = Button(root, text="New Window", command=open_new)
btn.grid(row=2, column=0, padx=5, pady=5)

# Right button: row 2, column 2
btn1 = Button(root, text="New Window", command=open_new)
btn1.grid(row=2, column=2, padx=5, pady=5)

# We add a new fake element here to fill row 1, so that buttons move to the bottom of the page
Frame(root).grid(row=1, column=0, columnspan=3)
root.rowconfigure(1, weight=1)  # This is to say that row 1 should expand in height to fill all available space
root.columnconfigure(1, weight=1)  # As above, this is to fill the page horizontally by expanding column 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Packing the two buttons to side `LEFT` and `RIGHT` instead of BOTTOM:

```py
btn = Button(root, text="New Window", command=open_new)
btn.pack(side=LEFT, padx=5, pady=5, anchor='s')

btn1= Button(root, text="New Window", command=open_new)
btn1.pack(side=RIGHT, padx=5, pady=5, anchor='s')
```

Alternatively you can simply create another frame to hold the two buttons and put the frame at the bottom of the window:

```py
bottom_frame = Frame(root)
bottom_frame.pack(side=BOTTOM, fill=X)

btn = Button(bottom_frame, text="New Window", command=open_new)
btn.pack(side=LEFT, padx=5, pady=5)

btn1= Button(bottom_frame, text="New Window", command=open_new)
btn1.pack(side=RIGHT, padx=5, pady=5)
```

Answer (score 0):

Would it be better like this without parameter in `pack()`?

You are missing `root.mainloop()`

```
Label(root, text="Game",font=('Georgia 15 bold')).pack(pady=30)
btn= Button(root, text="New Window",command=open_new)
btn.pack()

btn1= Button(root, text="New Window",command=open_new)
btn1.pack()

root.attributes('-fullscreen', True)
root.mainloop()
```

Screenshot:

[image]